# In chisel, how to define a common ZERO for all Data type?

Tags: chisel

In parameterized module or functions, there might need to initialize a general Chisel Data type to "0" according to the type.

that is there should be a value equals (ZERO).asInstanceOf[T], where T<: Data.

(0.U).asInstanceOf[T] works for most of T<:Data, but not for T==Bool.

How to fix this?

```
def delays[T <: Data](x: enter code hereT, n: Int): List[T] ={
  assert(n>0, "Register delays require n > 0")
  val dx = RegInit((ZERO).asInstanceOf[T])
  dx := x
  if (n <= 1) List(dx) else dx :: delays(dx, n-1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you need is [asTypeOf](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/api/index.html#chisel3.core.Data@asTypeOf[T<:chisel3.core.Data](that:T):T).

Not all of the Chisel type information is stored in the static Scala type, some is stored in the object itself. Thus you need to do a special Chisel-cast like so: `0.U.asTypeOf(x)`

Comment: I thought Bool is a subtype of Data. but I got this error message:
    Test.scala:33: inferred type arguments [chisel3.Bool.type] do not conform to macro method asTypeOf's type parameter bounds [T <: chisel3.core.Data]
    poke(lb.io.test.valid, 0.U.asTypeOf(Bool))
                                  ^

Comment: `Bool` is a subtype of `Data`. The problem here is actually that `Bool` itself is the companion object used to construct instances of class `Bool`. What you want for `.asTypeOf` is an *instance* of `Bool`, not the companion object. Try this: `0.U.asTypeOf(Bool())`